# double division keeps giving me "inf"

Tags: c, double

I have a function which the return type is double.

my return statement is

```
return sum / (double)(weight/100);
```

where sum is a double and weight is a int.
I wrote printf statements before the return to check the values
sum was 25.000 and (double)(weight/100) gave me .500
but the return statement gave me "inf"

what is wrong with it ?

Comment: Are you sure that it was (double)(weight/100) and not (double)weight/100 that gave you .500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `weight` is probably an integer, so `weight/100` gives `0`, and `sum / 0.0` gives `inf`. Just rewrite it as:

```
return sum / (weight/100.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing integer division between `weight` and 100. How about:

```
return 100 * sum / weight;
```

With this way you multiply 100 and `sum` and you get a double again since `sum` is double. Then you divide the double result with the integer weight and you don't face the problem of integer division.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the weight first to double. Now it divides an int by 100 to a new int. (Which probably becomes 0) Then you cast it to a double and then you divide sum by this answers. I would change it to:

```
return sum / ((double)weight)/100;
```